# Platform Device Drivers

Tags: drivers, devices, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compilation

I was just going through the code of kernel. I have a raspberry Pi board. I want to interface the touch screen with my board.

I want to develop the Platform driver for that. As per the documentation of Driver Model in kernel source, I am not getting that much clarity.

Can anybody just guide from where should i start to develop the Platform Device Driver ?

Answer (score 1):

Platform drivers are used to communicate with platform devices like the controllers in your SoC I2C, SPI, etc.

To develop a platform driver start reading the kernel source for platform driver framework. The important APIs are -

platform_device_register()
platform_driver_register()

You will get the source code of platform device/driver framework in drivers/base directory. Start giving print statements in driver code and compile.

Thanks,
Shaibal